# I would like to store a number's digits individually in an array/ arraylist, and write them out in a given order. Any suggestions what im doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, numbers, digits

I would like to store a number's digits individually in an array/ arraylist, and write them out in a given order. Any suggestions what im doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    
    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10; // Store digit in a variable
        number = number/10;
        digits.add(digit); // Add digit to the list
    }
    System.out.println(digits.get(1, 0)); //given the scanned number eg. 23, i'd like to write out 32
}
}
```

Comment: What is the output when you run this? If it's an exception, please copy and paste it into the question. If the output is wrong, please add the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: `digits.get(1, 0)` is incorrect syntax. You have to loop through the ArrayList to read the whole reversed number. Also, instead of using an ArrayList, you can simply build the reversed number within the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you just need to print the digits ? because the number are correctly added in the list.

Just replace

```
    System.out.println(digits.get(1, 0));
```

with:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.print(digits.get(i));
        }
```